# Apache: tmp is not writable

Tags: apache-2.2, tmp

I've installed Drupal on a new webserver and I get the following errors:

```
warning: is_writable() [function.is-writable]: open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/tmp) is not within the allowed path(s): (/customers/rollergirl.ch/rollergirl.ch:/var/www/diagnostics:/usr/share/php) in /customers/rollergirl.ch/rollergirl.ch/httpd.www/drupal/sites/all/modules/imagecache/imagecache.install on line 37.

ImageCache Temp Directory   /tmp is not writeable by the webserver.
```

I guess this happen because the server is not configured with a writable tmp folder

I don't have access to Apache configuration file (I only know for sure it is Apache).

Could you suggest me what to do ? I can only contact web server service ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you change Drupal settings:

http://drupal.org/node/15368